# Change ChartCursorBalloonText in Javascript Amcharts

Tags: amcharts

Hi i am using javascript AmCharts and this one’s an AmSerialChart. Although we are showing dates in the category axis, the requirement is such that we cannot show them as dates but as strings. Keeping this in mind, I would need to show the chartcursor balloon text as the full date, for example ‘08/05/2013’. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

i hope i undestood you right.

to let amcharts understand your date format specify dataDateFormat
http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#dataDateFormat

then turn on parseDates in the categoryAxis to enable the date parsing
http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#parseDates

you might want to format the category axis as well
http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#minPeriod
http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#dateFormats

and here the latest step to format the chart cursor which you've asked for
http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ChartCursor#categoryBalloonDateFormat

I hope that will help you :)